# Append number to end of string in Powershell for loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Trying to append the index value of a for loop to the end of a string, but I'm having some trouble getting the desired result.

Here's a short code block of what I'm working with:

EDIT:

```
$apiKey = "ZZZ-ZZZZZ"
$octoHeader = @{ "X-Octopus-ApiKey" = $apiKey }

# GET Source deployment process from Deployment Scaffold project
$json = irm "http://octopusserver/api/deploymentprocesses/deploymentprocess-projects-123" -Headers $octoHeader

$DeploymentSteps = $json.Steps

# Hash table to hold steps
$steps = @{}

function Get-StepType
(
  $StepType
)
{
  foreach ( $Step in $DeploymentSteps | where { $_.Name -eq $StepType } )
  {
    return $Step
  }
}

function Copy-Steps
(
  $StepType,
  $StepCount
)
{
  $Step = Get-StepType -StepType $StepType 

  1..$StepCount | % {

    $Step.Id = ''
    $Step.Name += $_

    # Add step to hash
    $steps.Add("step$($steps.Count + 1)", $step) 
  }  
}

Copy-Steps -StepType 'Service' -StepCount 2 

$steps
```

And this is the result:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
step1                          @{Id=; Name=Service12; Actions=S...
step2                          @{Id=; Name=Service12; Actions=S...
```

The result I'm after is: Name=Service - 1, Name=Service - 2, etc. I see what's happening, but I'm not sure the proper way to get what I'm after.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `Copy-Steps` you need to actually copy steps:

```
function Copy-Steps
(
  $StepType,
  $StepCount
)
{
  $OriginalStep = Get-StepType -StepType $StepType 

  1..$StepCount | % {

    $Step=$OriginalStep.PSObject.Copy()
    $Step.Id = ''
    $Step.Name += $_

    # Add step to hash
    $steps.Add("step$($steps.Count + 1)", $step) 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1..5 | % { [String]::Format("Step {0}", $_) }
```

or thereabouts

Comment: Same result. 

Removed the inner foreach to simplify a little:

  1..$StepCount | % {    
    $Step.Id = ''
    $Step.Name = [String]::Format("$($StepType) - {0}", $_)  

    $steps.Add("step$($steps.Count + 1)", $step)       
  }